# Marker Clustering with Bokeh

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh

Quick question, is it possible to create clustered markers using bokeh? 
For example, something like: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Or is this simply something that is beyond the scope of what bokeh's use case is?

Comment: It could probably be done by pre-defining groups and view zoom levels in each row of a column data source and using filters to pick elements to render. Otherwise it is not a built in feature.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Thanks!